# EF Core join table for one-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes: User, Post and UserPost. User and Post have a 1-to-many relationship. There's a third join table called UserPost that tracks the up/down vote each post gets. To ensure each user can only upvote/downvote once, the ID (PK) of this table is a composite key of User and Post ID.

```
public class User {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Post> Posts {get; set;}
}

public class Post {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public User User {get; set;}
}

public UserPost {
    public Guid Id {get; set;} // This should be a composite key of User ID and Post ID
    public Guid PostId {get;set;}
    public Guid UserId {get;set;}
    public VoteType VoteType {get;  set;}
}

public enum VoteType {
    Up = 1,
    Down = 0
}
```

In my DB Context class I defined the User/Post relationship like this:

```
builder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Posts)
    .WithOne(p => p.User)
```

Now I want to define the relationship for the UserPost model but not sure how to go about it. So far I have:

```
builder.Entity<UserPost>()
   .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.PostId })
```

Does it require anything further?

Comment: You should remove the `UserPost.Id` property and you should define the foreign key constraints for `UserId` and `PostId`. Your `HasKey` approach for the composite primary key is correct. Take a second to decide, whether you more often want to know "all votes of a user" or "all votes related to a post", then put the order of key columns accordingly - but this is just a minor detail, not functionally required.

Answer (score 0):

Write your whole relationship as follows:

```
public class User 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Post> Posts {get; set;}
}

public class Post 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}

    public Guid UserId {get; set;}
    public User User {get; set;}
}

public UserVote // Rename this from UserPost to UserVote to keep naming consistency. 
{
    public Guid PostId {get;set;}
    public Guid UserId {get;set;}
    public VoteType VoteType {get;  set;}

    public Post Post {get; set;}
    public User User {get; set;}
}

public enum VoteType {
    Up = 1,
    Down = 0
}
```

Now, *Fluent API* configuration for the `UserVote` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.Entity<UserVote>(e =>
   { 
       e.HasKey(uv => new { uv.PostId, uv.UserId}); //<-- Here is the composite key.
       e.HasOne(uv => uv.Post).WithMany().HasForeignKey(uv => uv.PostId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
       e.HasOne(uv => uv.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(uv => uv.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
   });
}
```

Comment: What is the first `WithMany` in relation to? Post? And with many what? Also what about the User/Post relationship I have in the original post? Is that not needed?

Comment: Why is `public Guid UserId {get; set;}` explicitly needed in Posts? Doesn't EF Core automatically create the UserId as a shadow property. Also, why do I not need `Id` property in `UserVote`?

Comment: @blankface an EF configuration of the form `HasXXX(x => x.RELATED).WithYYY()` always refers back to the currently configured entity. So in the code above, this is a way of saying "with many `UserVote`", without actually exposing a referenced `UserVote` collection within `User` or `Post`.

Comment: @grek40 Thanks for that. Do I still need to define the User and Post relationship as I did in the original post?

Comment: @blankface same story... you do need to have a navigation property at least at one end of the relation, but you can implicitely define the other end without a navigation property.

Comment: @grek40 Cheers. `e.HasKey(uv => new { uv.PostId, uv.UserId});` is not creating an Id column in the db though. It's missing from the migration script as well.

Comment: @blankface there is no ID column in an M:N table. The primary key is a compound key of the two foreign key properties. This ensures, that each User-votes-for-Post relation is unique. There is nothing in EF or in SQL that enforces an ID column for each table.